# ansible ansible_default_ipv4 set wrong interface

Tags: linux, deployment, ansible

I am trying to configure a host and automatically select the relevant interface.
For that I am trying to run the Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: Set the list of interfaces to be configured
  network_interfaces_to_configure: "{{ ansible_interfaces | difference([ ansible_default_ipv4.alias, 'lo', 'docker0' ]) }}"
```

For some reason it stores in `network_interfaces_to_configure` an interface that is deactivated — it sets it to `enp1s0f1` and it should be set to `enp1s0f0`

The host have the following interfaces:

- lo
- docker0  (virtual)
- enp1s0f0 (hardware connected and enabled)
- enp1s0f1 (hardware disabled and without any physical connection)

I also validated that the default gateway is set to `enp1s0f0`.

Comment: What is the value of `ansible_default_ipv4.alias`? Most probably, what you want is just: `network_interfaces_to_configure: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.alias }}"`

Comment: i got this via ansible myhost.com  -m ansible.builtin.setup:
"ansible_default_ipv4": {
            "address": "xx.xx.xx.200",
            "alias": "enp1s0f0",
            "broadcast": "xx.xx.xx.201",
            "gateway": "xx.xx.xx.222",
            "interface": "enp1s0f0",
            "macaddress": "xxxxxxxx",
            "mtu": 1500,
            "netmask": "255.255.255.254",
            "network": "xx.xx.xx..200",
            "type": "ether"
        },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you end up with the wrong interface there is because you are excluding the correct one in your `difference` filter.

```yaml
difference([ ansible_default_ipv4.alias, 'lo', 'docker0' ]) 
##               ^--- it is excluded because of this addition 
##                    of `ansible_default_ipv4.alias` in the list
```

Now, as you stated that `enp1s0f1` should be excluded because it is an inactive interface, then you will have to dig further in the properties of those interfaces.

In order to do this, you have to know that the list inside `ansible_interfaces`, corresponds to `ansible_*` facts that list more information for those interfaces.

For example, in your case, you will have those facts:

- `ansible_lo`
- `ansible_docker0`
- `ansible_enp1s0f0`
- `ansible_enp1s0f1`

With information like:

```yaml
ansible_lo:
  active: true
  device: lo
  ipv4:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    broadcast: ''
    netmask: 255.0.0.0
    network: 127.0.0.0
  mtu: 65536
  promisc: false
  type: loopback
```

So, maybe, a better idea would be to create a fact and exclude interfaces based on their `active` and `type` properties.

Something like:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    active_interfaces: "{{ active_interfaces | default([]) + [item] }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"
  when: 
    ## only include active interfaces
    - lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ item).active
    ## exclude local loopback interfaces (`lo`)
    - lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ item).type != 'loopback'
    ## exclude bridge interfaces (`dockerO`)
    - lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ item).type != 'bridge'
```

Then, use that variable in `network_interfaces_to_configure`:

```yaml
- network_interfaces_to_configure: "{{ active_interfaces }}"
```

---

Here would be an example of what this gives on my own setup, given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        active_interfaces: "{{ active_interfaces | default([]) + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"
      when: 
        - lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ item).active
        - lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ item).type != 'loopback'
        - lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ item).type != 'bridge'

    - debug:
        var: active_interfaces
```

This yields:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=eth0)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=tunl0) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=docker0) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=lo) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=services1)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=ip6tnl0) 

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  active_interfaces:
  - eth0
  - services1
```